# Set max rows INSERT limit MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where the admin can upload details of more users. Before uploading he has to choose a **limit**; let's say he selects **30 users**. So, can I set a limit on that MySQL table to **allow inserting only 30 rows** and not more? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Simple answer: no.  Not at the MySQL level.

Comment: Ok thanks @StevenMoseley. Wasn't sure if there was any such feature.

Comment: you can use `INSERT ... SELECT syntax`..

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO `user_details` (fields) 
SELECT d.detail
FROM 
    (SELECT 'asdasd' as `detail` FROM dual) d
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        LIMIT 30
    ) i
```

- For higher limit values, this trick won't work I suppose
- You need access to the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema.

example fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15ea4/5

Comment: That will limit a single insert statement, not max rows inserted

Comment: @StevenMoseley, it will insert up to 30 rows.

Comment: @Sebas: But I do not want to upload 30 rows at one go. First time it could be 10, second time 20 or some other combinations.

Comment: @rishiJasapara pass the number as an argument then

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a database access library, a sophisticated way to solve this is to open a transaction at the start of SQL query and do a commit to the data-base only in case you did not passed the limit, pseudo code (using soci):

```
transaction tr(*db);
//your SQL query that ends in "RETURNING id"
if (id < 30) tr.commit();
else throw;
```